# SharePoint online list template not retaining unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, list-template

I have created a list with unique permissions and then saved it as a template. When I use this template to create more lists on my SharePoint Online team site the new list does not retain the unique permissions. Instead it inherits from site level. I have also created unique permissions on the list template gallery but the template doesn't inherit from the the template gallery, instead it inherits from the site.

Any ideas about how to make this work? Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

List templates do not maintain permissions. If you need to provision custom lists you're going to need to use code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have not used code yet to do any sort of customisation in SharePoint online. It would be very helpful if I could be guided to the right direction in getting started with this. Thank you